# error compiling qt for visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I want to compile qt 4.8 for visual studio 2010 but having a problem. I know a similar question is being posted but I'm still facing this problem after trying suggested solutions. I really need help.

1: I installed the visual studio add-in

2: I created New folder c:\Qt\4.8.0\ and extracted the Qt source code to it.

3: I set the environment variables:

QTDIR = C:\Qt\4.8.0-\

QMAKESPEC = win32-msvc2010

4: I added to the Path variable: C:\Qt\4.8.0\bin

5: I created the folder C:\Qt\4.8.0\jom extracted the latest version of jom files to it

6: I restarted windows then opened the VISUAL STUDIO command prompt and ran
    cd C:\Qt\4.8.0
    configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2010

But i get the following error:
    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory.
Seems it can't find the platform header files so i downloaded and installed windows sdk but i'm still getting the same errors. What do i do next please?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the Windows SDK, go to the Start menu and find the Visual Studio Registration Tool under the Windows SDK entry. Use that to link the SDK to VS2010 and recompile.

**EDIT**

Follow the instructions for VS2010 in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) :

Comment: Sorry, because i'm a total beginner but how do i link the SDK to the VS2010

Answer (score 0):

Add environment global variable INCLUDE with the include path of windows.h